# Python: Change values in a pandas DataFrame column based on multiple conditions in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes **df_x** and **df_y** and I want to update a ‘**SCORE**’ column that they both have in common. I want to update the score column with a score of **100** if the following conditions are met:

- Age <= 45 **AND** column Banned != 1 OR column chargeback !=1

My trial below did not work. Any inputs?

```
if df_x.AGE_DAYS <= 45 and (df_x.BANNED != 1 or df_x.CHARGEBACK != 1):
    df_x['SCORE'] = 100
 
if df_y.AGE_DAYS <= 45 and (df_y.BANNED != 1 or df_y.CHARGEBACK != 1):
    df_y['SCORE'] = 100
```

**Outcome**: Basically, the 'Score' column should update the existing value with a 100 or do nothing at all if the above described criteria are met.

*To set up a sample testing enviornment:*

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0], [100, 0,0], [46, 1, 0]], columns=['AGE_DAYS', 'Banned', 'Chargeback'])

print(df)
```

**Desired output**:
Updated score column added to show that score values outside the criteria specified not changed. Only values changed if they meet the criteria of this search!

```
AGE BANNED  CHARGEBACK  SCORE   "UPDATED SCORE"
45    1        0         75      75
33    0        0         45      **100**
44    0        0         77      **100**
235   0        1         75      75
43    1        0         88      88
21    0        0         23      **100**
1     0        0         56      **100**
432   1        1         12      12
```

Comment: You are expected to add a sample of input data and your expected output as text, You can look at [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: how are you getting 100 in updated score bcz there `Age <= 45` doesn't satisfying?

Comment: Opps Good Catch! Updated!!! @AnuragDabas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
c=(df['AGE']<=45) & df[['BANNED','CHARGEBACK']].ne(1).all(1)
#OR(both conditions are same so choose any one)
c=(((df['BANNED'].ne(1)) & (df['CHARGEBACK'].ne(1)))) & (df['AGE']<=45)
#your condition
#also notice that you need & in place of | in your condition that you posted in question
```

Finally use `mask()` method:

```
df['UPDATED SCORE']=df['SCORE'].mask(c,100)
```

OR

you can also use numpy's `where()` method for this:

```
#import numpy as np
df['UPDATED SCORE']=np.where(c,100,df['SCORE'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using apply

```
df_x['SCORE'] = df_x.apply(lambda x:100 if x['AGE_DAYS'] <= 45 and (x['BANNED'] != 1 or x['CHARGEBACK'] != 1)

df_y['SCORE'] = df_y.apply(lambda x: 100 if x['AGE_DAYS'] <= 45 and (x['BANNED'] != 1 or x['CHARGEBACK'] != 1)
```

Comment: I seem to get a syntax error here. I tried to debug but idk why it would return "an invalid syntax starting at df_y portion"

Comment: hmm strange can you paste the traceback?